# Jquery-CSS bug fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html-lists

I've got the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href><img src/></a></li>
    <li><a href><img src/></a></li>
    <li><a href><img src/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Because of fixing some CSS bug I need to know which of these image links is "mouseovered"
Then in the Jquery script I need selector which is something like

```
$('a img').mouseover(function(){
var imgElement = $(this);
if ('a img[3]') { // if the hovered link is the third
imgElement.animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginLeft: "-150px"
            }, 1500 );
```

The question is how to get the second or third 'a img' in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/M2KAF/

```
var $imgs = $('a img');
$imgs.mouseover(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    if ($imgs.index($that) === 2) { // if the hovered link is the third
        $that.animate({
            width: "315px",
            height: "225px",
            marginLeft: "-150px"
        }, 1500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('a img').each(function(i){
 $(this).mouseover(function(){
    if (i == 2) { // if the hovered link is the third
      $(this).animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginLeft: "-150px"
            }, 1500 );
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not move the `if` outside. Now *all* elements have an event bound, of which all but one do nothing.

Comment: I tght he might have different conditions for other images so we need it inside the mouseover event, otherwise it can be moved out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery's nth child selector http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following you properly. If you want the third `<li>`'s `<img>` you can just use `$('ul li:eq(2) a img')`.

Comment: I think it would be :eq(2) or :nth-child(3)